# Can I skip an ActionFIlter in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an action filter attribute on a base class all my controllers inherit from. I want it (the filter) to work on all methods EXCEPT one. Can it be done? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little hackish, but you could test for the action in the filter's OnActionExecuting method, like so:

```
var controllerName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
var actionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
if (controllerName == "Foo" && actionName == "Bar")
{
    return;
}
//do normal stuff
```

Comment: The other option is to create a custom Action Attribute which encapsulates this functionality. I did that with a custom Authorize Attribute which skips the Login method on my account controller.